# Unable to get JS document.getElementById to work in my rails view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In my `views/user/index.html.erb`, I have:

```
<div id="heading">There are <%= @user.length %> users in here</div>
```

In my `assets/javascripts/stuff.js`, I have:

```
document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = "No one here";
```

Yet when I reload the page, the js snippet doesn't work, the text is unchanged. However, when I put `alert("test")` in my `stuff.js file, an alert box pops up, letting me know at least the JavaScript is being picked up.

What am I missing for the `getElementById` to work?

Comment: Are you waiting for the DOM to be ready? Can you share stuff.js code?

Comment: Sure, my stuff.js is only one line: 
document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = "No one here";
It's a test project so I deliberately kept it minimal

Comment: Try using: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
  document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = "No one here";
});` to wait for the DOM to be loaded or use if you are using jQuery try with `$(document).ready` https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I tried your solution again, don't think I changed anything else but now it works!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. I am glad it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using rails 5 with `Turbolink 5` you should use this event to make sure that the element is there.

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
    document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = "no one here";
});
```

If you are using a previous version of Turbolink use `page:load` instead of `turbolinks:load`

Comment: I just added the above to my stuff.js file, still get no changes. Should I be putting it in a different file? Or if the element is not there, should I check somewhere for an error alert?

Comment: What is the version of Rails and Turbolinks are you using?
No you should put it in your stuff.js file.
for errors you can check your browser console, or just use `alert()` for debugging.

Comment: My Rails version is 5.0.0.1, Turbolinks is '~> 5'. I will read into how to use the browser console to look for JS errors right now...

Comment: This is the server logs not the console log. You can open the browser console by pressing F12 in your browser (Chrom or Firefox), then press `Console`, If there is an error you will find it there.

Comment: The console doesn't show any errors when I reload it. I'm think it must be due to JS firing too soon to detect the element though.

Comment: Nice answer! Maybe saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're running your script before the DOM load. If that's the case, try putting the call to your code at the end of your body tag.

```
<body>
<div id="heading">There are <%= @user.length %> users in here</div>

...

<script src="assets/javascripts/stuff.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: You were right that my script was running before the DOM loaded, I tried putting the script at the end but it had no effect. The solution above, adding document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"... did the trick though. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.